# Search a directory and all files within for a certain string

Tags: batch-file, find

Hello I'm very new to dos, but I need a batch file that searches through all files in a directory for a certain string and copy those lines to a new file.

```
FOR /R %%G IN (*) DO FIND "string" C:\ "%%G" > result.txt
```

But I can't get it to work

Comment: the path for the find command?

Comment: `for /r` set the drive letter automatically ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me through the command prompt:

```
for /r %G in (*) do @find "import" "%~G" >nul 2>&1 && @echo %G
```

**EDIT:**
To see lines and numbers:

```
for /r %G in (*) do @findstr /n "issue" "%~G"  2>null && @echo %G
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `"%~G"` instead of just `%G`, otherwise there'll be issues with filenames containing spaces.

Comment: I can't get it to work! My guess is that i'm missing something very basic

Comment: sorry got it working! :) But this only gives me the files with the string, I need the lines which include the string

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to make the results end up in a new file?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean with this...To mark the beginning of every new file or to output the result in a file?

Comment: To output the result in a file

Comment: just set `>>result.file` or something like that at the end.

Comment: THANK YOU! You have really been to alot of help!

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr /N "string" *.* > result.txt
```